# Gamekit multiplayer and different screen sizes

Tags: swift, game-center, gamekit

I am very new to gamekit, so I am starting with a basic game. 2 players on the screen and allow them to just move around at this point.

I am testing the game with an ipad and a phone, so I am quickly realizing the ipad user has a lot more real estate instead of the same space being resized.

How do I setup the level to be the same amount of space on any device, but just magnified accordingly?

Answer (score 0):

Try this for all the nodes that you want to be resized use the .setScale() method:

```
let scale = frame.width/667
node.setScale(scale)
```

667 is the approximate width of an iPhone 6. Feel free to play around with the number 667 to get the right magnification.

Basically what this does is it scales the node according to the size of the screen.

Note: Scaling may decrease resolution of any sprites used.